# Laravel: How to reuse pieces of code in several methods of a controller

Tags: php, laravel, methods, controller

I am building a form in order to both create and edit records.

Since I am using a lot of relational information (tables) from several catalogs and shown in the for as a select box (Select2), I need to retrieve all the data to be shown in those HTML select tags.

So, let's say that in my controller in the `create()` method, I call that info like so:

`create()` method of **MyController.php**:

```
public function create(Token $token){
    //Tags
    $universities      = University::orderBy('name')->get();
    $countries         = Country::orderBy('name')->get();
    $programs      = Program::orderBy('name')->get();
    //... and many more

    return view('my.form.create',[
        'universities' =>  $universities,
        'countries'    =>  $countries,
        'programs'     =>  $programs,
        'token'        =>  $token
    ]);
}
```

How do I do to reuse that piece of code `//Tags`

```
//Tags
$universities      = University::orderBy('name')->get();
$countries         = Country::orderBy('name')->get();
$programs      = Program::orderBy('name')->get();
//... and many more
```

in order to reuse it for the, let's say, `edit()` method or other ones??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put them in a separate method in your class that just returns the data as an array and then call that method from your `create` and `edit` methods:

```
protected function getFormData()
{
    return [
        'universities' => University::orderBy('name')->get(),
        'countries'    => Country::orderBy('name')->get(),
        'programs'     => Program::orderBy('name')->get(),
    ];
}
```

Then your `create` and `edit` methods would look something like:

```
public function create(Token $token)
{
    $data = $this->getFormData();

    return view('my.form.create', $data);
}

public function edit(Token $token)
{
    $data = $this->getFormData();

    return view('my.form.edit', $data);
}
```

If you're not planning on adding anything to the data array then you could simply inline the call instead:

```
return view('my.form.edit', $this->getFormData());
```

Comment: Thanks to that approach I could even extend that `getFormData()` method to a Trait!!!

Comment: @Pathros I would only suggest making it into a trait if you're going to be using it in other controllers as well. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method to handle that part individually, such as:

```
/**
 * Tags from universities.
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
protected function getUniversities() {
    return University::orderBy('name')->get();
}
```

Then you can use it in other methods of the class by just doing `$universities = $this->getUniversities()`.

The `getUniversities()` method can also live in a parent class.

Answer (score 0):

If you will reuse the code in a major part of the controller i would say to use the constructor of the controller

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->universities      = University::orderBy('name')->get();
    $this->countries         = Country::orderBy('name')->get();
    $this->programs      = Program::orderBy('name')->get();   
}
```

this will load all the values you declare in each controller method.

if not you can create a helper in your app folder that return the values you need.

Comment: Also check out automatic injection example from docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#resolving

Comment: I don't recommend performing database queries or other I/O in a controller's constructor. If you have actions that don't use that data, they will spend time loading that data for no reason